# Installations: Could not process request. Application offline. (installations/app-offline) error with firebase

Tags: firebase, google-chrome

I am getting an error when trying to run my application locally:

[image]

I am only getting this error in the chrome browser. I have tried different things, but I am not sure why it is Chrome specific.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a package that has changed but my application is able to run in other browsers. I know for a fact that this is firebase related and I there is no code change that prompted this error. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That could all well be, but we have no way of knowing how your code uses Firebase. Without an MCVE it'll be hard for us to replicate the problem and thus help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this isn't a Firebase issue, but rather a Chrome one. My Chrome for Android the last day or two has been acting up and saying it's offline when it isn't, which I suspect is leading to `navigator.onLine` to be false. This would lead Firebase to throw this error, for example during auth token refresh: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/7d916d905ba16816ac8ac7c8748c83831ff614ce/packages/installations/src/helpers/refresh-auth-token.ts#L60-L62

My app works fine on localhost on Chrome for Mac 87.0.4280.88, but is throwing this error on Chrome for Android 8.0.4280.101, Android 11.

Comment: This is what I am dealing with as well! Did you find a solution for it?